# Install package locally

Tags: python, pip

I use `python`'s `pip` to install packages. Now I want to install `scipy`, which is already installed on the system, but an old version and on a part of the system where I don't have access to. If I try

```
pip install scipy
```

`pip` rightfully tells me that the package is already installed. If I do

```
pip install scipy --upgrade
```

`pip` tries to upgrade the package but I don't have the access rights to do that.

How can I tell `pip` to install the package local to my user and to ignore the other `scipy` package?

Comment: `pip help install` suggests `--user`.

Comment: Ah, I checked `pip help`, but not `pip help install`. It seems to work (taking a while). If you elevate this to an answer, I might accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best way for avoid override packages it's using a virtual environment. Python has it's own virtual environment and you could install it by:

**Python 2.7**

```
> sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
```

**Python 3**

```
> sudo apt-get install virtualenv
```

With modern `python` versions, `virtualenv` is usually included. Once installed, you could generate a virtual enviroment typing:

```
> virtualenv venv
```

This would create a folder in the current directory named `venv` (you could name it whatever you want). In this package the libraries will be installed.

So, it's time to activate the virtual environment

```
> source venv/bin/activate
```

You could verify the environment has been activated by checking the prompt changes. If it happens, all the packages installed using pip will be installed locally.

```
(venv)> pip install scipy
```

You could check [this website](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) for more info.

Don't forget that you eventually have to clear your `$PYTHONPATH` variable, in order for it to not pick up other packages.

Comment: Python has been providing its own virtualenv-like package for a while now: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: you are invited to edit or improve the answer with that info

Comment: I fixed my problem. I had clean up my `$PYTHONPATH` variable. I added this to your answer. Thanks for the help.